# Detect Dragging stopped Google map android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am writing a code to get map fragment's center lat-long and find some places around it. For this I am passing the center's lat-long to a web api to fetch the places, when user drags the map. Since I am using  CameraChangeListener to get center's lat-long, it returns multiple locations on each drag and hence increasing unwanted network call.

I want to detect drag-stoped and call the after few seconds so that user gets enough time to point his desired location.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround for determining drag start and drag end events:

You have to extend `SupportMapFragment` or `MapFragment`. In `onCreateView` you have to wrap your `MapView` in a customized `FrameLayout` (in example below it is the class "TouchableWrapper"), in which you intercepts touch events and recognizes whether the map is tapped or not. If your "`onCameraChange`" gets called, just check whether the map view is pressed or not (in example below this is the variable "mMapIsTouched").

Example code:

UPDATE 1:

return original created view in `getView()`
use `dispatchTouchEvent()` instead of `onInterceptTouchEvent()`
Customized FrameLayout:

```
private class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mMapIsTouched = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mMapIsTouched = false;
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

In your customized `MapFragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, 
            savedInstanceState);

    mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
    mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);
    return mTouchView;
}

@Override
public View getView() {
    return mOriginalContentView;
}
```

In your camera change callback method:

```
private final OnCameraChangeListener mOnCameraChangeListener = 
        new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        if (!mMapIsTouched) {
            refreshClustering(false);
        }
    }
};
```